# Rails: select_tag value changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr, html-select

I'm having an issue with `select_tag`. Searched a lot and couldn't find anything that really helped.

What I want is a dropdown which displays 3 options (Price, HH and Percentage) and, according to the user selection, updates the value of my class' attribute `:weight`. Also, I'd like to refresh the page as soon as the user chooses an option and the 'default' option displayed in the refreshed page would be the option chosen previously.

This is what I have in the view, that won't store the value in my `:weight` attr:

`<%= select_tag :weight, options_for_select([['Price', 1], ['HH', 2], ['Percentage', 3]], :weight), :onchange => "location.href = '#{system_url}'" %>`

Thanks in advance, Ian

Comment: How are you handling this in your update action? Also, on a side note, why would you want to do a refresh that way?

Comment: Do I have to handle this in the update method in my controller? The refresh action just redirects to the page i'm in... is there a better way? @HargrimmTheBleak

Comment: I don't understand the need to refresh in the first place. Next, if you show the code for the form and the update action, this would help understand the problem better.

Comment: @HargrimmTheBleak I don't HAVE to, but I think it is easier than doing it by ajax. I have no form and no code in my update method related to this, do I need it?!

Comment: OK so how are you handling this server side to update the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You must send an ajax request on change event in selectbox. Which will fetch results for you and then update the :weight option for you in 'ajax:success' event